# JQuery load only last n lines of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in a webpage where I need to load only the last n-th lines of a textfile.
For example:

```
<div id="contentdiv" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">here comes the output of the logfile</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#contentdiv" ).load( "logs/logfile.log" );
  });
</script>
```

But I only need the last 5 lines of the logfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming that line separator is `\n`**

**Using the load method** will limit you to first load everything and then remove

try

```
$( "#contentdiv" ).load( "logs/logfile.log", function(response){

    $( "#contentdiv" ).html(response.split("\n").slice(-5).join("\n"));

} );
```

But this will show all the lines first and then only last 5.

So, you need to hide this div first

```
$( "#contentdiv" ).hide();
$( "#contentdiv" ).load( "logs/logfile.log", function(response){

    $( "#contentdiv" ).html(response.split("\n").slice(-5).join("\n"));
    $( "#contentdiv" ).show();

} );
```

**Another option** could be

```
$.get( "logs/logfile.log", function(data) {
  $( "#contentdiv" ).html(data.split("\n").slice(-5).join("\n"));
})
```

This will load the div only once with last 5 lines.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer! I will accept your answer in 3 minutes (time limitation for new members)

Comment: @yoano sure, glad to help.